# Adding a modifier to a phrase with a comma

Tags: adjectives, commas, modifiers

Here is the sentence in question:

"...line of performance apparel is perfect for any race, 5k to 50k. "

Is that the proper way to modify race?  What is this rule called?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is just a case of a prepositional phrase in which the preposition is implied, rather than stated outright:

> ...line of performance apparel is perfect for any race, *[from]* 5k to 50k.

It's not incredibly formal, but I doubt it would be flagged as an error in most contexts.